# Why can't I have new as a method for my Users controller and routes defined in one line in play framework?

Tags: scala, playframework, scala-2.10, playframework-2.3

I am new to scala and play framework so, please excuse me if this a naive question. I have been building my web application in Ruby on Rails and in Rails' Controller I can say:

```
def new
 # my ruby code for rendering new template/view
end
```

Now, I tried to do the same in play(*app/controllers/Users.scala*):

```
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

object Users extends Controller {

  def index = Action {
    Ok("Hello Users!!")
  }

  def show(id: Long) = Action {
    Ok("Hello Users!!")
  }

  def new = Action {
    Ok("Hello new Users!!")
  }

  def edit(id: Long) = Action {
    Ok("Hello Users!!")
  }

  def create = Action {
    Ok("Hello Users!!")
  }
  def update(id: Long) = Action {
    Ok("Hello Users!!")
  }

  def destroy(id: Long) = Action {
    Ok("Hello Users!!")
  }

}
```

Do you see this method:

```
  def new = Action {
    Ok("Hello new Users!!")
  }
```

It's where play throws this error:

```
Compilation error
identifier expected but 'new' found.
In ./first_app/app/controllers/Users.scala at line 16.
13    Ok("Hello Users!!")
14  }
15
16  def new = Action { 
17    Ok("Hello new Users!!")
18  }
19
20  def edit(id: Long) = Action {
21    Ok("Hello Users!!")
```

Now, I would understand if `new` is reserved keyword or something, but it doesn't make sense to me. Yes, it works if I rename it to: `new_user` but that's not an ideal situation for me(considering I could do the same in Rails)?

Also, my routes:

```
# Home page
GET     /                           controllers.Application.index

GET     /users                      controllers.Users.index
GET     /users/new                  controllers.Users.new
GET     /users/:id                  controllers.Users.show(id: Long)
GET     /users/:id/edit             controllers.Users.edit(id: Long)
POST    /users                      controllers.Users.create
PUT     /users/:id                  controllers.Users.update(id: Long)
DELETE  /users/:id                  controllers.Users.destroy(id: Long)
```

Can anyone please tell if it's possible to define all `/users` related routes in one line?

In Rails, I could do: `resources :users` and it used to take care of all CRUD routes for `/users`, is there anything similar to it in Play framework? Can't seem to find these in docs.

Comment: Just tip: use `add` for the first action, and you'll avoid clash with reserved words, languages differs, that's normal even in real life ;)

Comment: @biesior Thank you for the tip. And what about routes? Is it possible to define ALL CRUD routes in one line?

Comment: shortly: no, it's not possible

Comment: I'm not sure I would use add.  Its too much like create. How about anew, which has roughly the same meaning as new.

Comment: @calasyr: that's why @4lex1v suggested to change it to `New` instead of `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new` in Scala, as well as in Java, is a reserved word which can't be used as a name, it's used to create new object (instances) of some class, in Ruby, if i'm not mistaken, it's a method on a class like `SomeClass.new`. You can bypass it and use `New` (with a capital letter) instead.

Comment: Oh, I thought so. That's why I had put it in the question. And what about routes?

Comment: @Surya I'm not working with Play, but i think yes, routes is just a text that's mapped onto some handling function, so you can't use it as a handler name, but it should be OK as a name for a route.

Comment: in Ruby, `new` is class method that's used to instantiate the object of the class. If I'm not mistaken same case is with Java/Scala?

Comment: @Surya no, in Scala and Java it's an [operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html), not a method.

Comment: +1, Thank you for clearing my doubt on `new`. Also, is it considered as good practice to define methods name starting with capital letters, like you suggested: `New`, `Edit` in Java/Scala? I should have known that I'm entering in a whole new dimension of programming world. :(

Comment: @Surya no, in Java and Scala you are using camel case for naming, starting with a low level case.

Comment: Note that you can quote identifiers that would otherwise be illegal using backticks.